# a bounded function is converge in measure, then its limit is also converge

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

If a series function, ${f_n} \rightarrow f $ in measure $\mu$, and $|f_n| \leq M$, how to show that $|f| \leq M$?

My instructor gave a hint as follows, but I do not believe the first inequality $\leq$ is right.

$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \mu(|f| > M + \epsilon) \leq \mu( |f_n| > M) + \mu(|f - f_n| > \epsilon)$, since $|f| \leq |f-f_n| + |f_n|$

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the triangular inequality as below:

$|f| = |f - f_{n} + f_{n}| \leq |f - f_{n}| + |f_{n}| \rightarrow |f_{n}| \leq M$
because $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ in measure $\mu$. Therefore, $|f| \leq M$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Philo. I am not quite sure whether converge in measure could produce $|f-f_n| \rightarrow 0$...

Comment: Yes. You are right. I think we can say that "$|f| \leq M$ almost everywhere" instead of pointwise by the definition of the convergence in measure $\mu$. Are there any other assumptions about $f_{n}$ and $f$ such as continuity?

Comment: By $\{x \in \Omega : |f| > M + \epsilon\} \subset \{|f_{n}| > M\} \cup \{|f - f_{n}| > \epsilon\}$ and the subadditivity of $\mu$, the first inequality is right.

Comment: I am guessing there should exist the case that $$
{x \in \Omega : |f_n| > M, |f-f_n| < \epsilon, |f_n| + |f-f_n| > M + \epsilon
$$. hence, I think $\subset$ should be $\supset$

Comment: There are many other ways to include $\{x \in \Omega : |f| > M + \epsilon\}$ by the union of two sets such as $\{|f_{n}|>M\} \cup \{|f−f_{n}| > ϵ\}$. One of the ways is the above case and I used that inclusion.

Comment: I get what you mean. Thanks, Philo.