# Bounded convergence theorem - 2M

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

[image]

Can someone please help me with where the 2M is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

By the triangle inequality,
$$\int_{B_n} |f_n-f| \mathop{d\mu} \le \int_{B_n} (|f_n|+|f|) \mathop{d\mu} \le 2M \int_{B_n} \mathop{d\mu}$$
where the last inequality is due to $|f_n| \le M$ and $|f| \le M$.

Comment: But is it not only f_n which is smaller than M?

Comment: @PeterMortensen See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980096/a-bounded-function-is-converge-in-measure-then-its-limit-is-also-converge)